# Priority or QoS on SQL Server 2008 R2 Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any method to set Quality of Service (QoS) or priority on stored procedures in SQL Server 2008 R2?

I have a ASP.NET 4.0 web application that exposes some reports that trigger a few long running non-critical report-type stored procedures.

This same application and database supports some real-time data feeds (reverse ajax) and other critical processes.

My problem is these long running non-critical stored procedures are sometimes adversely impacting the performance of my critical processes, especially when a timeout occurs on the long-running Sprocs or the rare deadlock event.

Is there any method to set a priority or QOS on the Stored Procedures to minimize the impact of non-critical stored procedures on my critical ones?

If this functionality is not supported in SQL Server, is there anything that can be done at the application level in my data access layer (ADO.NET) to set priorities, perhaps using a different connection string?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *why* your report procs are adversely impacting the real-time processes.  If it's because of resource contention (CPU, etc.), then you *might* be able to do something.

But if it's because of lock contention (blocking/deadlocking), then there's no simple external fix, you'll have to either 1) change something in how the report procs themselves work or 2) reschedule/reconfigure things so that they don't conflict, or 3) live with it.

Comment: It is mostly because of CPU Utilization & large tables. The report-type sprocs are read-only (I have added NoLock) but they are reading against some of the same tables that are used by my critical  data-feed tables and cause CPU to peak from an avg of 5-10% to 50-75%. 100% accuracy of the report type sprocs is not critical, but their impact on the rest of the system is a problem.  RAM is not an issue. The server Dual Quad (8CPU) Processor with 32GB RAM. I am wondering if adding (MAXDOP = 1 or 2) to the report SPROCs would help? These low-priority cpu-heavy SPROCs are run approx. every 60 secs.

Comment: Yes, MAXDOP is one of the things that you can do if it's a CPU problem.